# PostgreSQL get latest rows/events for all users

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

Working on PostgreSQL 8.x (AWS Redshift)

I have a db structure like this:

```
userId: varchar, tstamp: datetime, event: string
```

So let's say I have the following rows

```
u2, t1, e1

u1, t2, e2

u2, t3, e1

u1, t4, e2
```

Where u1 and u2 are userids, t[1..4] are timestamps where t1>t2>t3>t4
and e1 and e2 are types of events.

So how do I get latest events performed by all users. So the output of the query would be:

```
u2, t3, e1

u1, t4, e2
```

Tried to understand using:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery
and
[PostgreSQL Selecting Most Recent Entry for a Given ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472731/postgresql-selecting-most-recent-entry-for-a-given-id)

But I guess m a slow brain. Couldn't get it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with Postgres' [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on(userId) userId, tstamp, event
from events
order by userId, tstamp desc;
```

For Redshift, you might be able to [this variant from one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10515391/320220):

```
select userId, tstamp, event from (
  select userId, tstamp, event, 
  row_number() over (partition by userId order by tstamp desc) as rownumber 
  from events
) foo
where rownumber = 1
```

Comment: Heyy.. running this on AWS Redshift. Sorry forgot to mention in question. 
Distinct On is not supported :(

Comment: Using the row number hack was something I had never thought of. I'm glad that it works :)

Comment: This is incredible!

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.userid,
       t1.date,
       t1.event
from table t1
where t1.date= (select max(t2.date) 
                  from table t2
                  where t2.userid = t1.userid);
```