# Select a specific row from a table with duplicated entries based on one field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which holds data in the following format, however I would like to be able to create a query that checks whether the reference number is duplicated and only return the entry with the latest date_issued.

```
ref_no          name      gender place      date_issued

xgb/358632/p    John Smith  M   London      02.08.2016

Xgb/358632/p    John Smith  M   London      14.06.2017

Rtu/638932/k    Jane Doe    F   Birmingham  04.09.2017

The result from the query should be; 

ref_no          name    gender  place       date_issued

Xgb/358632/p    John Smith  M   London      14.06.2017

Rtu/638932/k    Jane Doe    F   Birmingham  04.09.2017
```

Is there a fairly straightforward solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Selecting Most Recent Entry for a Given ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472731/postgresql-selecting-most-recent-entry-for-a-given-id)

Answer (score 0):

assuming the date column is type `date` or `timestamp`

```
select distinct on(ref_no) * from tablename order by refno,date desc;
```

this works beacuse `distinct on` supresses rows with duplicates of the expression in parenthese.