# Something like SELECT DISTINCT ON, but for N > 1

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

If I want to get the first row, or the most recent single row on a field in postgres, `select distinct on` seems great, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464181/1052117).

`DISTINCT ON` is a syntax for wanting exactly 1 entry.  But what if I want the N most recent entries?  How would I transform this:

```
CREATE VIEW your_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM your_table a
ORDER BY id, date DESC;
```

But for

"Select the most recent n=2 entries per id" rather than "select the most recent n=1 entries per id?" ?

I assume it's an group by subquery, but I'm not quite seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query with n > 1 you typically use a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by "date" desc" as rn
  from the_table
) x
where rn <= 2;
```