# How to use row_number in a where clause

Tags: postgresql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, column-alias

I'm trying to use window functions to get the most recent n records, following [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570170/something-like-select-distinct-on-but-for-n-1/61570644#61570644):

I have:

```
select 
   id,
   blah,
   row_number () over (
     partition by blah, my_id
     order by datetime) rn,
   theme
from documents
where theme = 'cats';
```

And I get:

```
 id | blah | rn | theme 
----+-----+----+-------
  1 |   1 |  1 | cats
  2 |   1 |  2 | cats
  3 |   1 |  3 | cats
  4 |   1 |  4 | cats
  5 |   1 |  5 | cats
  9 |   2 |  1 | cats
  8 |   2 |  2 | cats
 11 |   3 |  1 | cats
 12 |   4 |  1 | cats
 13 |   5 |  1 | cats
 14 |   6 |  1 | cats
(11 rows)
```

Which is great.  But I want not more than 2 rows, `rn <= 2`, for example.  I imagine this as something like:

```
select 
   id,
   blah,
   row_number () over (
     partition by blah, my_id
     order by datetime) rn,
   theme
from documents
where theme = 'cats' and
rn <= 2;
```

but I get:

```
ERROR:  column "rn" does not exist
LINE 15: rn <= 1;
         ^
```

I know I can make this a subquery like the linked question, but there must be syntax I'm missing for putting the row_number in the where clause, right?  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a derived table:

```
select id, blah, them
from (
  select id,
         blah,
         row_number () over (partition by blah, my_id order by datetime) rn,
         theme
  from documents
) x
where theme = 'cats' 
and rn <= 2;
```

This is basically syntactic sugar and does not cause a performance overhead.

Comment: Is there a performance difference if my where clauses are in the inner select vs the outer?